# OS X 10.9.x failed login attempts previous days

Tags: macos, logs

I have found some answers on here but need to check something. Is there a way to check the failed login attempts form previous days?

I have tried:

```
var/log/secure.log
```

but that only gives me results for the current day and I need them for the past 4 days ideally.

Have also used

```
cat /private/var/log/system.log | grep "Failed to authenticate"
```

And again only todays results.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As the logs is rotating, you could find the info you need on previos files. After some predefined size, the logs files are moved and compressed. See example image.

[image]

So, you have to look after files that suits your dates requirements and uncompress it using `gunzip filename.gz` command.

Then you can `grep` your pattern on those files.